# Correct way to provide the "name" of a "PostalAddress" on type "Place"

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

I have a page about a village named "San Felipe", and since I want it to have a richer snippet in search engines displaying its postal address, I decided to add to it some address details (including its postal code). I have read in the schema.org docs that [`PostalAddress`](http://schema.org/PostalAddress) can be used on a `Place`. I tested adding a `name` for a `PostalAddress`, and the search result preview in [Structured Data Linter](http://linter.structured-data.org/) showed the value of the `name` below the page link.

But when I also added values into the `addressCountry`, `addressLocality`, `addressRegion`, and `postalCode`, the `name` disappears from the search results preview and is automatically replaced by the address properties mentioned above. So I am confused if the `name` property is intended as a shorter way of adding a postal address, or if it should contain only the name of the main item (in this case, "San Felipe"):

```
<script type='application/ld+json'>
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "AdministrativeArea",
    "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressCountry": "country name",
        "addressLocality": "city name",
        "addressRegion": "region name",
        "postalCode": "2800",
        "name": "San Felipe, city name, region name, country name 2800"
    },
    "name": "San Felipe"
}
</script>
```

As seen in the screenshot below, the `schema:name` of `schema:address` ("San Felipe, Santo Tomas, San Juan, Santiago") is ignored in the search results. However, it is displayed when I do not specify the `addressCountry`, `addressLocality`, `addressRegion`, and `postalCode`. So I am not sure of its purpose.

[image: Structured Data Linter screenshot]

Comment: The `name` which the tool showed is the one for `AdministrativeArea`, not the one for `PostalAddress`, right? Or did you manage to get the `name` of the  `PostalAddress` shown, too?

Comment: @unor: Sorry for being confusing. I uploaded a screenshot above, kindly check.

Comment: When I remove the four properties from `PostalAddress` (except `name`), it doesn’t display this `name` in the snippet.

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing that out. I must have been confused with so much markup. So is it then safe to delete this `name` as it does not seem to serve any purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Structured Data Linter](http://linter.structured-data.org/) just gives an example how a snippet *could* look like. For this purpose, the tool only shows selected properties. Whether or not the Structured Data Linter shows something in this snippet should never affect your decision which structured data to provide.

So if you think your `PostalAddress` could benefit from a `name`, provide it.

> I am confused if the `name` property is intended as a shorter way of adding a postal address, or if it should contain only the name of the main item (in this case, "San Felipe")

Schema.org doesn’t define what the `name` for a `PostalAddress` should be. I think there are two common cases:

- In the typical case, it would be the name which would also be used when addressing a piece of mail. This isn’t necessary the same name that’s specified on a parent item (if it has any). But even if it’s the same name, it can still make sense to provide it again for the `PostalAddress`, because a consumer might not necessarily also take the parent item into account.
- If specific properties (like `addressCountry` etc.) can’t be used (e.g., because the CMS doesn’t output these in separate fields), you could provide everything you have in the `name`.

  (In that case, you could also consider to use `address` with a string value, instead of a `PostalAddress` item value.)

If it’s not the address of an organization or a person, and if you can provide all the necessary properties for each address part you provide, I would omit the `name` property.

Comment: This is most helpful info. Thank you very much. Yes, I have many places that do not accurately fit into these address fields, so I'll also provide a name.

Comment: This is most helpful info. Thank you very much. Yes, I have many places that do not accurately fit into these address fields, so I'll also provide a name.